# Ionic 2 CSP on android

Tags: ionic-framework, content-security-policy

My app does not display camera images, instead it shows broken image, but for other images (screenshots ...) I don't face this problem.

here is the error shown : Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

this happens only for the camera images.

any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this line : 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">` to your index.html?
 Also, add the following :
  `<allow-navigation href="*"/>`
 `<allow-navigation href="file://*/*" />`
`<allow-intent href="*"/>` 
`<access origin="*"/>`

to your config.xml, and tell me if it works! 
And just in case you didn't add it already, add the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin !

**Edit** : also try adding these three more lines :

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
```

and removing your `<base href="/">` from your index.html.

Comment: the error disappeared but another one came in front : ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, even the images do exist on device.

by the way I am using the cordova camera plugin.

here is a full error : 
GET file:///9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAME…IxnjGKlYkIoB4JwR2oBO2xEwCMQQPmyBUchOzYG5/vZyAfapGOxOB0AxUDEmPfnnB5oHHc/9k= net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Are you using an emulator? Its probably just a path error. Can you debug it on Chrome maybe? But I suggest you to modify your <base href> to the following : <base href="./"> in your index.html. Tell me if this changes anything

Comment: no I am not using an emulator, on chrome debugger it says :  GET file:///9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICA‌​gQDAgICAgUEBAME…Ixnj‌​GKlYkIoB4JwR2oBO2xEw‌​CMQQPmyBUchOzYG5/vZy‌​AfapGOxOB0AxUDEmPfnn‌​B5oHHc/9k= net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND



I changed the <base href="./"> but nothing.

and I removed the android platform and install it again but still suffering from this issue

Comment: Aw... this is getting hard ! Ill have a look tomorrow, not promising anything aha. The code of the error doesn't matter I guess, its more about the fact that it can't get images, so Im still thinking it has to be related to the path somehow... Try adding the allow markups line by line ?

Comment: I think it is a bug or something in the framework itself, but I am not sure about it, because the other projects worked just fine, and did not suffer from this issue.

Comment: IMO I don't think its a bug... it must have an explanation, as I said, it may come from a wrong path, you have to look into it ! Do you use the same things in your others projects ? Like getting images etc... Can you try one last thing? I edited my answer, try that, if that doesn't work Im sorry Ill have to let it down :(

Comment: THANKS! still having that issue. I am going to start a fresh project then copy the other project files one by one while testing (desperate way to find the source of the problem ). THANK you again for your instructions.

Comment: ahah you're welcome, too bad we didn't find out !! I also had many problems when deploying my app on device sometimes... but most of the time (or even, all the time aha) there is an explanation !! don't worry :)