# Photos are not showing Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, base64

I'm building an Ionic app and trying to use **camera** native plugin to take photos and then show it on the screen, script is working when i create a brand new project and put it inside, but it's not working on the project i'm working on.

I thought there is an issue with my package.json, but i updated all packages, i removed file and camera plugins, installed them again but the issue is still the same, 
this is the output i get 
[image]

But when i create a new project and try the script, the photo shows perfectly!

I'm just stuck and do not know what could be making this conflict or where to look, kindly assist

HTML:

```
<ion-card *ngIf=resultImageArray>
  <img src="{{ resultImageArray }}" />
</ion-card>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Camera, CameraOptions} from "@ionic-native/camera";
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';
export class HomePage {

public imageURI: any;
public imageName: any;
public fileCreated: boolean = false;
public imageString: any;
resultImageArray: any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private file: File, private 
camera: Camera, private toastCtrl: ToastController,) {}
getImageFromCamera() {
const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 20,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    allowEdit: true
};

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
    this.imageURI = imageData;
    this.imageName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    this.file.checkDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'ImagesDemo')
        .then(() => {
            this.fileCreated = true;
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("checkDir: Error");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            this.presentToast("checkDir Failed");
        });
    if (this.fileCreated) {
        this.presentToast("Directory Already exist");
    }
    else {

 this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory,"ImagesDemo",true)
            .then((res) => {
                this.presentToast("Directory Created");
            }, (err) => {
                console.log("Directory Creation Error:");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            });
    }

    let tempPath = this.imageURI.substr(0,this.imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    let androidPath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/ImagesDemo/';
    this.imageString = androidPath + this.imageName;

    this.file.moveFile(tempPath, this.imageName, androidPath,this.imageName)
        .then((res) => {
            this.presentToast("Image Saved Successfully");
            this.readImage(this.imageString);

        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Image Copy Failed");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            this.presentToast("Image Copy Failed");
        });

    this.toDataURL(this.imageURI, function (dataUrl) {
        console.log('RESULT:' + dataUrl);
    });
    }, (err) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    this.presentToast(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}


presentToast(msg) {
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: msg,
    duration: 2000
});
toast.present();
}

toDataURL(url, callback) {
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        callback(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
}

readImage(filePath) {
let tempPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
let imageName = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

this.file.readAsDataURL(tempPath, imageName)
    .then((res) => {
        this.presentToast("Image Get Done");
        this.resultImageArray = res;
    }, (err) => {
        this.presentToast("Image Get Error");
    });
}
}
```

And this is the error i get from the console when i remote debug the app:

(index):1 Refused to load the image 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QBAAl+B//2Q==' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I cut the image base 64 code because it's very long and may not be very comfortable to read, so why it's showing without errors when i create a new project and in this particular project it's not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2 CSP on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788573/ionic-2-csp-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i figured this out so i thought someone might be looking for this

i added this line into my index.html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
img-src 'self' data: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com;
script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com;
" />
```

now everything is working perfectly