# ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'Module'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

When building Android App from Ionic4 using "ionic cordova build android"

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "campusrides_v2.0",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^5.15.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.5.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.2.1",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^2.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^6.2.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.0.0",
    "firebaseui": "^4.0.0",
    "firebaseui-angular": "^3.4.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "sharp": "^0.22.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^5.0.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "2.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.8",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "xcode": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {
        "GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "[-------------------------]",
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.12.0",
        "LOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires access to your location for navigation purposes"
      }
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
}
```

It gives the following error in the browser console when executing "ionic serve"

> Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8100/favicon.ico' because
>   it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please do tell what more details needed to solve this issue. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: have you tried the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788573/ionic-2-csp-on-android?

Comment: the following log entry `localhost/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` seems truncated.

Comment: @MStoner yes tried and got, Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: @MartinZeitler what can we do to solve the truncate issue?